# Rails tasks name clash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I have several rake tasks and some of them have methods with the same name, but only one one of them is execute. 
e.g.

task1 has method bla
task2 has method bla but bla from task1 is getting executed.

How do I prevent such a behavior in tasks?